# Count number of nights booked per month with check-in and checkout dates

Tags: excel

I have a dataset with 5 different rooms and a list of bookings with check-in and checkout dates. I've pasted an image below and here is a link to the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-RfagDAzhaNJoLEqi9rSEtwpBA1y9CVTOQRmnpIEim4/edit?usp=sharing

[image: [enter image description here]

**Challenge:** help me sum the number of nights booked per room per month in Table B. I have used the formula

```
=SUMIFS($F$3:$F$14,$A$3:$A$14,B$17,$B$3:$B$14,">="&$A18,$C$3:$C$14,"<="&EOMONTH($A18,0))
```

but when a booking falls across two months (eg row 4) it doesn't get counted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A formula that counts partial months' occupation (bookings starting in one month and ending in another) would be impractical. Either your Table A must therefore be modified to do that job or a derivative of it prepared to split the data by month. Table B is a derivative of that table and not really part of this problem. Forum rules limit one thread to one question for a reason, and this is it. By asking two questions rolled into one thread you lose focus. I recommend you revise your question.

Comment: thanks for the advice, now edited into one question

Answer (score 1):

Version II.  This one seems to be working regardless of the dates used.  There is probably a way of simplifying it even further but at least it works (even if convoluted):

```
    =SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Out]>=EOMONTH(G5,0))*(G5>=Table1[In])*(DAY(EOMONTH(G5,0))))
    +SUMPRODUCT((DATE(YEAR(Table1[In]),MONTH(Table1[In])+1,0)=EOMONTH(G5,0))*(Table1[Out]>EOMONTH(G5,0))*(EOMONTH(G5,0)+1-Table1[In]))
    +SUMPRODUCT((DATE(YEAR(Table1[Out]),MONTH(Table1[Out])+1,0)=EOMONTH(G5,0))*(Table1[Out]-G5))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would add two Columns: Total Check-In and Total Check-Out as in the Sample Picture.

[image: Sample Picture]

**Formula of Total Check-In** is :

```
E2=IF(MONTH(B2)<>MONTH(C2),C2-B2-(C2-DATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2),1)),C2 -B2)
```

It basically calculates all the days of the stay for the month of the Check-in.

**Formula of Total Check-Out** is:

```
F2=D2-E2
```

Which calculates the days of the stay of the month of the Check-Out.

Then I would write the formula that put it all together as:

```
B11=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$7,$A$2:$A$7,B$10,$B$2:$B$7,">="&DATE(YEAR($A11),MONTH($A11),1),$B$2:$B$7,"<="&EOMONTH($A11,0))+SUMIFS($F$2:$F$7,$A$2:$A$7,B$10,$C$2:$C$7,">="&DATE(YEAR($A11),MONTH($A11),1),$C$2:$C$7,"<="&EOMONTH($A11,0))
```

Which calculates in the first SUMIFS the total days of stay if the month appears in the Check-in column and in the second SUMIFS the total days of stay if the month appears in the Check-Out column.

Comment: not sure I follow? this is just a sample selection of data, sometimes the checkout date is several days past the end of the month (eg check-in 31/01/20 checkout 04/02/20)

Comment: Hello, I've edited my answer with more details and a sample picture to explain myself better. If you find any mistake you'll let me know ;)